# Is there any way to create a single page application using angular 7 without using node and npm, can we add npm dependencies in script tag

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I have to set up an application in angular 7 in a single page so that all the dependencies are loaded by the script tag not using npm and node.

Comment: Sure, you can, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It is possible in theory, but very cumbersome in practice.

Comment: Your question can be read as : can I install libraries and all their dependancies manually instead of using a packet manager like npm ? Yes ofc you can, but why on earth would you want to do this ? I recommend you install npm, angular-cli and get familiar with how to generate and build a single page app using angular-cli. Probably the easiest and fastest way to have your page running.

Comment: @wentjun
Actually, I have to render this page under the setup of Angular 1, as we can not set up two versions of angular on the same system, so I have to render this page stand-alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand how the framework works under the hood.

To answer you in TL;DR : yes, you can.

To explain more :

When you create an Angular application, you actually install a full framework : this framework is made to ease your coding, allowing yo to use libraries and dependencies to not invent the wheel again.

Indeed, to use those libraries, you have to use NPM.

But Angular is written in Typescript : this code that you type, is then compiled into JS, to be deployed on a server.

When compiled, the CLI creates bundles of code : those bundles are essentially JS bits that all work together to make a SPA.

This means that even with "npm and node", you're still achieving what you're asking.

That would be a bummer to create a project without the CLI or NPM ! At this point, it's probably better to use a library rather than a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Angular relay on some technology during building the project like typescript and other , but after you build your project you will have just a static javascript , css , html files

Another a protech is building angular element and inject therse to your web project with just script tag without any angular dependence

In both cases you need to create an angular project and build it then  can use the static files like javascript and inject these files to your project

check this angular has a lot of integration with other project like react native , ionic ,electron and othes [angular resources](https://angular.io/resources)